# Code-signing .NET assemblies before starting a download to a client's web browser

Tags: c#, download, code-signing

I'm using signtool.exe to digitally sign auto-generated downloadable content from C# calling the command line and then stream the file to the client browser. The problem is that while the signature seems ok on the web, the downloaded file seems to be lacking a segment of it. If you right click on the generated file on the server, you see a perfectly good signature and if you view the certificate, it says that "this digital signature is OK".

The downloaded file looks different. While it's 15 bytes smaller, it's not corrupted but while the issue name is intact, it says that This digital signature is not valid.

Is something happening during transit? I'm using this code to sign the content:

`Response.Clear();

Response.ContentType = "application/exe";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + filename);

Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());

Response.TransmitFile(filePath);`

Thanks in advance,
Frank.

Comment: Are you using a certificate to sign your assemblies that would not be from a trusted authority? That would be one of my first guesses.

Comment: +1 I need this information. can you also geve some info how you sign it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the response sent to the client in the headers the correct length or the wrong (short) one?  Use Fiddler or Firebug to check.

If it's correct, but the client isn't receiving the data, try a Reponse.Flush() after the TransmitFile.  I think that's probably just superstition, but a lot of people seem to do it.

Comment: The response is correct. Response.Flush() seems to have done it. Thank you.

Comment: It's still bewildering why the response would trim some metadata.

Comment: It's not that it's 'trimmed metadata', it's just that there's some unflushed data left in a stream buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your `FileInfo fi` before reading the length for the `Content-Length` header, it may be caching the old length prior to the signing or so.

Comment: The fi is instantiated after having signed the application. Also, there is an issuer name in the downloaded certificate.